# i cant open or import weka project.jar file in weka software

Tags: jar, weka

I want to import a project weka.jar file to Waka software or open the project file.jar with Waka software, but I can't. How to open project weka file.jar in Waka software?

im try in weka 3.9.1 and weka 3.8.6 and weka 3.9.6 and instaled jdk 21

Comment: Can you provide a link to this Waka software? Does it support integration of Java applications like Weka?

Comment: weka is software in link "https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/"

Comment: So you're not trying to use/import weka.jar in another software called waka. Can you run `java -jar weka.jar` from the command-prompt/terminal in the directory containing the `weka.jar` file? If not, what error message do you get? Weka installers tend to come with Java bundled, so there is no need to install Java separately. But you could try downgrading your Java to [version 11](https://adoptium.net/temurin/).